# How do you log a user out with wp_logout?

Tags: headers, logout

I can get `wp_logout` to work, but not without generating lots of warnings ('PHP warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent').

`wp_logout` calls `wp_clear_auth_cookie`, which calls `setcookie`, and the cookies have to go with the HTTP headers. I'm calling `wp_logout` inside the page (in the header or footer), hence the problem.

So, how exactly am I meant to programmatically log a user out? I could do this in response to an ajax request, but that seems way over the top. Thanks.

*EDIT*

Current code as follows:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'fp_onload_php2');
function fp_onload_php2() {
   $slug = basename(get_permalink());
   if($slug != 'club-login')
      return;

   $jsmsg    = '';
   $loggedin = false;
   if(is_user_logged_in()) {
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $loggedin = $current_user->has_cap('customer');
   }

   if($loggedin && isset($_GET['logout'])) {
      wp_logout();
      $jsmsg    = 'You have been logged out.';
      $loggedin = false;
   } else if(!$loggedin && isset($_GET['logout']))
      $jsmsg = "You are not logged in.";

   if(!$loggedin)
      echo
         "<script type='text/javascript'> fp_onload_js2(0, '" . $jsmsg .
         "'); </script>\n";
   else
      echo
         "<script type='text/javascript'> fp_onload_js2(1, '" . $jsmsg .
         "'); </script>\n";
}  // fp_onload_php2()
```

Comment: Where/how are you using `wp_logout()`? Post the code please.

Comment: you've mostly answered your own question- you have to call `wp_logout` before any content is sent to the browser.

Comment: Maybe `delete_user_meta($user_id, 'session_tokens');` can help? This can also ban specific user. Once user's session has been deleted and that user (or even your user) reload the page, it will be automatically logout by WordPress.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `wp_logout` in your own code, its probably best to `exit` or `wp_redirect` immediately afterwards.

You can call `wp_set_current_user(0)` after `wp_logout()` to manually log the user out instantly, if you need to continue executing PHP but don't want the user to be logged in.

Comment: Since WP 5.3 fixed [issue 35488](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35488) wp_logout() includes the wp_set_current_user(0)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't great, but seems to work. It's not as simple as calling `wp_logout` before any content is sent, because the user may or may not be logged out before the rest of the page loads (I don't understand this). In my case, the page contents depend on whether or not the user is actually logged in (the menus change, and some JS code is called to display content differently).

for this code, a logout request redirects to the login page, with a GET parameter of `logout=1`. This is tested on the login page, which then calls `wp_logout`, and redirects back to the login page with a GET parameter of `logout=0`, to force a refresh.

```
add_action('init', 'check_logout');

function check_logout() {
   if(!isset($_GET['logout']) || ($_GET['logout'] != '1'))
      return;

   // get_permalink() and $post are not available here, so:
   $path = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
   if($path != "/login/")
      return;

   if(is_user_logged_in()) {
      wp_logout();
      header("Location: http://fubar.com/login/?logout=0");
      exit();
   } 
}  // check_logout()
```